# Can't sort mysql table rows alphabetically

Tags: mysql, sorting

I've got records of items in a table. The items are a mix of records that begin with letters and numbers. I can't get them to sort correctly (Alphabetically, numbers on top). Here's what I'm using to call the table.

```
SELECT * FROM `cog_name` ORDER BY `cog_name`.`name` ASC
```

Shouldn't this work? I'm getting a large part of the entries with numbers at the top, then alphabetized records below that. **HOWEVER**, about halfway down, it starts "re-listing" another set in alphabetical order.

```
Example query result:
SELECT * FROM `cog_name` ORDER BY `cog_name`.`name` ASC
--------
name
--------
1 car
2 horse
3 rocket
apple
banana
carrot
1 car
2 horse
3 rocket
apple
banana
carrot
```

Entries are all unique names, unlike my example.

Comment: Any whitespace at the start of the field?

Comment: Might you have spaces, linebreaks or tabs prefixing the first set of alphabetic entries?

Comment: To get a clearer picture of what's going on, you might try running `SELECT name, ORD(name) FROM cog_name ORDER BY name ASC`. The `ORD(name)` part will give the character-code of the first character in `name`, letting you see if there's any leading whitespace (as Michael Berkowski suggests) or any other weirdness like that.

Comment: how about trying something like "select name, trim(name) from cog_name order by trim(name)"?  That should get rid of trailing or leading spaces.

Comment: How about `SELECT name FROM cog_name where name = TRIM(name)` just to check.

Comment: Thanks everybody! I'm working in phpmyadmin, and it wasn't displaying a leading space on several entries. I had to export the data and check in my text editor to see it. Squashed that bug! Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: to see where there are problems, do a "select concat("|",name,"|") ... " then whitspace will show up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TRIM function:

```
SELECT TRIM(name) FROM `cog_name` ORDER BY TRIM(name) ASC
```

That ought to do it!